# How Can I set up a conditional format in openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am still fairly new to Python and I wanted to create an automated task to filter out all sales data that post negative margin % and highlight them in red for further investigation.  I just made up an example below but every time I run the command the new excel file populates only a blank workbook.. am I making a clear mistake?

SALES ID    Sales           COST          GP$       Margin %
1          $2,000.00       $1,000.00    $1,000.00   50.00%
2          $6,000.00       $4,500.00    $1,500.00   25.00%
3          $100.00         $27.00       $73.00      73.00%
4          $1,000.00       $1,200.00   -$200.00    -20.00%

Formula below:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = 'margin.xslx'
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule, FormulaRule
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Create fill
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111', end_color='EE1111', fill_type='solid')
ws.conditional_formatting.add('e2:e5',
CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'], fill=redFill))
wb.save("test2.xlsx")
```

Comment: You're always creating a new workbook, never opening the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("margin.xlsx")
```

Using `wb = Workbook()` creates a new workbook